# how to get individual value from array list in wordpress with php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to get a single value from the array in PHP, Wordpress, I have tried more code, but I am unable to get the values. I have given below using my code. Please help me anyone and save me.

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_confirmation WHERE user_id=$user_id");
   if($result)
    {
        foreach ( $result as $print )
        { 

        echo $cand[0]->['Cand'];
        }
   }
```

This is my array values

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 100  [comment] => wait for the moment 
          [Cand] => Dossier incomplet [candConfdate] => 2020-01-03 
          [datetrapedaCand] => 2020-01-09
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_confirmation WHERE user_id=$user_id");
   if($result)
    {
        foreach ( $result as $print )
        { 

        echo $print->Cand;
        echo $print-> comment;
        }
   }
```

You can get all individual value according to above example

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_confirmation WHERE user_id=$user_id");
if ($result) {
    foreach ($result as $print) {
        //$print is object, use -> to access properties of the object.
        echo $print->id;
        echo $print->comment;
        echo $print->Cand;
        echo $print->candConfdate;
        echo $print->datetrapedaCand;
    }
}
```